# How to compile/link a unittest in a Linux Makefile correctly?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

On a Linux system I want to compile and link an unittest using the `gtest` framework. I am using the following `Makefile`:

```
CC := g++ # This is the main compiler
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGET := bin/myapp
TEST := tester

SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
CFLAGS := -g
LIB := -pthread -L lib  -L /usr/local/lib -lsqlite3 -lboost_thread -lcrypto
INC := -I include 

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo " Linking..."
    @echo " $(CC) $^ -g -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    @echo " $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    @echo " Cleaning..."; 
    @echo " $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

# Tests
$(TEST): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo " Compiling test..."
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  test/tester.cpp $(INC) -c -o build/$(TEST).o
    @echo " Linking test..."
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -pthread test/tester.cpp /usr/lib/libgtest.a $(LIB) -L build build/tester.o -o bin/$(TEST) 

.PHONY: clean
```

The compilation of the main application (`myapp`) works just fine, but I get into trouble compiling/linking the test file located in the `test` directory.

When I do NOT include any other library (from `src` or `include`, respectively) then the following line

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -pthread test/tester.cpp /usr/lib/libgtest.a  $(INC) -o bin/$(TEST)
```

just works perfect and creates a runnable executable. However, when I try to include some library from my project in `tester.cpp` like e.g.

```
#include "MyClass.h"
```

(which is defined as `MyClass.h` in `include` and as `MyClass.cpp` in `src`) then, with the above `Makefile`, I get various `undefined reference` errors (in what I have labelled as the 'compile' stage for 'tester').

I am not sure if I should compile the file `tester.cpp` first and then link all the libraries, or if I should do everything in one step? I do not know how to do either.

Any advice on fixing this Makefile above is appreciated...

Comment: You need to compile MyClass.cpp and link the corresponding object file MyClass.o into your executable. It's not enough just to add the #include in your source file tester.cpp.

Comment: Please see updated instructions - I was ablle to just compile the file `tester.cpp` and create a file `tester.o`. Now I think I link everything together correctly by using: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -pthread test/tester.cpp /usr/lib/libgtest.a $(LIB) -L build build/tester.o -o bin/$(TEST)`. Now I still get `undefined reference` errors and `multiple definition` errors...

Comment: Your link command still doesn't specify MyClass.o anywhere.

Comment: The multiple defintions come from having both `tester.cpp` and `tester.o` on the link command line -- you get everything in `tester.cpp` twice.  Get rid of `tester.cpp` on the link command line.

Answer (score 2):

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT),$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
OBJECTS := $(filter-out $(BUILDDIR)/main.o, $(OBJECTS))

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(BUILDDIR)/main.o
    @echo " Linking..."
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LIB)

tester: bin/$(TEST)

bin/$(TEST): build/$(TEST).o $(OBJECTS)
    @echo " Linking test..."
    $(CC) $(INC) -pthread $^ /usr/lib/libgtest.a $(LIB) -L build -o $@
```

P.S. Please don't edit the question like that, after you have answers. If you want to make a change (that doesn't render the existing answers meaningless), add new test to the bottom of the question, preferably with "**EDIT:**".

Comment: Running `make tester` gives me a `multiple definition of `main'` error. This makes sense, as the object `test.o` is created from the main application C++ file `src/test.cpp`, which also contains a `main` function (as the unittest file `test/tester.cpp`. Any way how to 'exclude' `main.o` or how to restructure the files / directories to avoid this problem?

Comment: @Alex: sorry, I'm accustomed to writing makefiles and test harnesses that are more selective about the source files. Give me a minute...

Comment: `make` now gives an error: `make: *** No rule to make target `build/test.o', needed by `bin/myapp'.` Similar for `make tester`...

Comment: I seem to need to create a separate entry to create `tester.o`, as my unitest source lives in `test` and not `src`. So it is not compiled when `make tester` is called...